# node-schedule should run every 1 hour in node js

Tags: node.js, scheduled-tasks, node-schedule

I have created crone job for every minute

```
import * as schedule from "node-schedule"

schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * *', async () => {
            console.log("running every minute")
        });
```

the above working perfectly for every minute. similarly I have task which has to execute for every hour. I tried like below

```
schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 */1 * *', async () => {
            console.log("running every minute")
        });
```

But unfortunately its not working every hour as expected. Is there any thing I'm missing

Comment: Also not sure if you are running it in the cloud but make sure your server didn’t go to sleep either.

Comment: @alecwilson sometimes I may restart my server for new changes to apply using pm2, how to rectify without restart.

Comment: I’m not really sure, you’d have to do some research into that

Answer (score 0):

i think you want "0 */1 * * *". Also you can use this great website to make sure your crontab is correct: https://crontab.guru/

Answer (score 0):

based on [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) the third * is hour

```
*    *    *    *    *    *
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │    └ day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun)
│    │    │    │    └───── month (1 - 12)
│    │    │    └────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    │    └─────────────── hour (0 - 23)
│    └──────────────────── minute (0 - 59)
└───────────────────────── second (0 - 59, OPTIONAL)
```

for every one hour just try

```
schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 */1 * * *', async () => {
        console.log("running every minute")
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wirte the cron string completely with length of 6 like "0 0 */1 * * *", because it is parsed backwards by schedule.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

For every Hour it should be :

```
schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 */1 * * *', async () => {
     console.log("running every hour")
 });
```